# 'strace' fixes hung process

Tags: unix, process, rhel, strace

I have a singlethreaded Unix process that communicates over [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) with other processes.

The problem is the following. When I start up the process it hangs (no busy loop) until I kill it.

The funny thing is, as soon as I attach with [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) to it, it continues to run with the expected behavior as if there wasn't any problem at all (always reproducible).

What could be the reason for this behavior? What effect has *strace* on the state of a process?

---

The cause of strace changing the behavior was, because we used openonload with a bug. As soon as we attached strace, the stack was moved back to the kernel and the problem was gone.

Comment: If the code is threaded, a race condition might be avoided by a controlling process which forces context changes at different points in code execution than happens when the code runs natively. Running a debugger on threaded code that has problems has sometimes resulted in the code not diplaying the problem - for me.

Comment: True, but the OP said "single threaded" :)

Comment: I have a similar situation... a hung process works alright if I attach to strace. Can anyone elaborate the explanation?

Comment: There is now an article about that: https://ayende.com/blog/198849-C/production-postmortem-the-heisenbug-server?Key=1eeda567-02a8-4bbb-b90f-557523973233

Answer (score 4):

Many years later, so probably with a completely different root cause, this blog post explains why attaching a tracer might fix hung system calls: https://ayende.com/blog/198849-C/production-postmortem-the-heisenbug-server?Key=1eeda567-02a8-4bbb-b90f-557523973233. It looks like running `strace` (or any other tool that uses the `ptrace` system call) can causing in "hung" system calls to return (with an exit code of `EINTR`).

Quoting the [ptrace man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

> Some system calls return with EINTR if a signal was sent to a
>
> tracee, but delivery was suppressed by the tracer.  (This is very
> typical operation: it is usually done by debuggers on every
> attach, in order to not introduce a bogus SIGSTOP).  As of Linux
> 3.2.9, the following system calls are affected (this list is
> likely incomplete): epoll_wait(2), and read(2) from an inotify(7)
> file descriptor.  The usual symptom of this bug is that when you
> attach to a quiescent process with the command
>
> ```
>    strace -p <process-ID>
> ```
>
> then, instead of the usual and expected one-line output such as
>
> ```
>    restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>_
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>    select(6, [5], NULL, [5], NULL_
> ```
>
> ('_' denotes the cursor position), you observe more than one
> line.  For example:
>
> ```
>     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {15370, 690928118}) = 0
>     epoll_wait(4,_
> ```
>
> What is not visible here is that the process was blocked in
> epoll_wait(2) before strace(1) has attached to it.  Attaching
> caused epoll_wait(2) to return to user space with the error
> EINTR.  In this particular case, the program reacted to EINTR by
> checking the current time, and then executing epoll_wait(2)
> again.  (Programs which do not expect such "stray" EINTR errors
> may behave in an unintended way upon an strace(1) attach.)

Comment: Can you summarise here? The link will break sooner or later.

Comment: Actually, the ptrace man page is the summary. But I added a sentence to summarize it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem only once and it was related to signal handling. It is one source of race conditions in single-threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that strace output simply slows down the process making deadlocks much less likely. I have seen this happen before with strace OR can happen when adding other debug printing or debug calls.

Deadlocks most often seen with multi-threaded interaction. But in your case you have multiple processes. If the strace frees up the processes every time then I guess the way you open the sockets or handshake on the socket is what is hanging. Buffering and blocking on the socket I think could be getting you into a process-deadlocked state.

Similar question but with a multi-threaded process, deadlock between threads instead of between seperate processes: [Using strace fixes hung memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433864/using-strace-fixes-hung-memory-issue)

Hard to generalise examples, especially as don't know what your different processes are doing or if they're sharing resources in some way? I will try . . .

1. Example with one object/resource which should be protected: 

   One process starts making changes on an object (e.g. adding items to a list/db table)

   Another process starts iterating the list/table.

   Danger of one of those processes iterating loop being confused and never exiting OR doing something worse like writing to invalid memory.
2. Example where object/resource is protected by mutexes

   The classic simple deadlock with two resources problem.
   ~ simpler than dining philosophers

   One thread/process grabs mutex on object A, does some work.

   Another thread/process grabs mutex on object B, does some work.

   Same thread/process needs to update object A, waits for mutex for A.

   Original thread/process needs to access object B, waits for mutex on B.

    . . . . . . . . . . . . @ . . . . . . . . . . . 

   Silence except for the noise of the wind and a tumbleweed blowing across the landscape.

    Deadlocked.